Flutter Widget Inspector have very large font size in VSCode
How to reproduce the problem -
click on "Run without debugging/Start Debugging" under "Run" option, open Widget Inspector.
I've read the other posts related to it and also cross checked the font settings just to be sure, I've tried using VSCodium and it's the same.
I've attached a screenshot just below,

Display - 1080x1920 @60Hz
Everything(extensions, vscode, OS, drivers.....) is up to date!
VSCode Extensions - ARB Editor, Better Comments, Dart Data Class Generator, Image Preview, Pretty XML, Remove Comments, VSCode
Icons, YAMLfmt for Visual Studio Code.
DevTools version: 2.37.2
IDE: VSCode
Connected Device:
CPU / OS: x64 (64 bit) windows
Connected app type: Flutter native (debug build)
Dart Version: 3.5.0
Flutter Version: 3.24.0 / stable
Framework / Engine: 80c2e84975 / b8800d88be
